# Is there an IOS specific Qt style existing which can replace the default Fusion style?

Tags: ios, qt

I'm trying to port a larger Qt app (~300KLOC) to IOS.
The app compiles and comes up, however instead of seeing something IOS'ish it displays the desktopp'ish "Fusion" style .
Grepping a bit in the Qt sources reveals that this is one of 2 official options (The other option is a windows style...).
Is there somewhere in the net a place where one attempted to create a more IOS looking style ?

Comment: Any comment why this got downvoted ?

Answer (score 1):

You have "macintosh" style for Mac OSX.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gallery-macintosh.html

You can check the availabe styles that you have in your app by using:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstylefactory.html#keys

Comment: I'm talking about IOS. I know that there is a Mac specific style on Mac. The available styles on IOS are "Windows" and "Fusion". Both do not produce the look I would expect from a Qt port to IOS.